# Widget unable to load

Tags: android, widget

I have an Android app with a corresponding Widget. It works perfectly in the past before 2017Nov. However, After my update to the Android studio, Gradle, and build tools. The app always build with an app that cause "Problem loading widget" 
[image: problem screen].

To make sure I am right I get back my code version before 2017Nov, and recompile. Problem still here. To solve this problem, my only way is to reboot the device. After reboot the device, the widget loads normally. My question:

- What kind of special system calls the Android device will trigger when restart the device?

More information: Actually I have done one more test. While my widget is live and no problem is shown after reboot, I uninstall it, reinstall it. Then problem loading widget immediately appear. After that reboot, problem gone.

Comment: can you share the screenshot

Comment: added the screenshot